# Execute a trigger on the same table if updating

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I need to execute a trigger that includes an `UPDATE` statement on the same table.

I have tried this code.  If I check the table, the row is updated, but I get an error message:

*Can't update table 'Orders' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger*

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS UpdateTotal;

DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER UpdateTotal BEFORE UPDATE ON Orders
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  UPDATE Orders P1
    SET NEW.order_total = NEW.order_total + 3.02
    WHERE order_id IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT MAX(order_id) FROM Orders) P2);
END

|

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't do all this in a trigger. According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html):

> Within a stored function or trigger, it is not permitted to modify a
>   table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the
>   statement that invoked the function or trigger.

explain more about requirement and table structure.